# Why reset the stack pointer register in FreeBSD?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, freebsd, stack-pointer

I'm trying to get a grip on assembler in FreeBSD.  In the [handbook's code example for a UNIX filter](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-unix-filters.html) the register esp is reset after each system call. The code in question is:

```
%include    'system.inc'

section .data
hex db  '0123456789ABCDEF'
buffer  db  0, 0, ' '

section .text
global  _start
_start:
    ; read a byte from stdin
    push    dword 1
    push    dword buffer
    push    dword stdin
    sys.read
    add esp, byte 12        ; <--------- Is this necessary?
    or  eax, eax
    je  .done

    ; convert it to hex
    movzx   eax, byte [buffer]
    mov edx, eax
    shr dl, 4
    mov dl, [hex+edx]
    mov [buffer], dl
    and al, 0Fh
    mov al, [hex+eax]
    mov [buffer+1], al

    ; print it
    push    dword 3
    push    dword buffer
    push    dword stdout
    sys.write
    add esp, byte 12        ; <--------- Is this necessary?
    jmp short _start

.done:
    push    dword 0
    sys.exit
```

This differs from the example on the [previous page of the documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-first-program.html):

```
 1: %include    'system.inc'
 2:
 3: section .data
 4: hello   db  'Hello, World!', 0Ah
 5: hbytes  equ $-hello
 6:
 7: section .text
 8: global  _start
 9: _start:
10: push    dword hbytes
11: push    dword hello
12: push    dword stdout
13: sys.write               ; <--------- ESP not adjusted after this. Why?
14:
15: push    dword 0
16: sys.exit
```

Why do these two examples differ? Why is something like `add esp, byte 12` necessary? Are the values not popped by the system call?  Is this necessary in 64-bit FreeBSD where arguments are not passed on the stack?  I imagined that the stack pointer would take care of itself.

Comment: Could you please quote the code you are confused by, or at least provide a link?

Comment: What do you mean by "the register esp is reset"? How do you "reset" a register? Do you mean that the original value is saved and restored? Do you mean that a value is *added* to ESP, like you would do to clean up a stack? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe after reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions , you will see that you need to detail your question a bit more. We cannot know exactly, what you refer to. FreeBSD follows the amd64 calling convention - so maybe you talk about that one?

Comment: I assume you are referring to a Unix Filter example in the [FreeBSD book/documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-unix-filters.html). That code is 32-bit code that uses an ABI where parameters are pushed on the stack right to left. You need to clean up the stack after in that case. If you are on x86-64 the calling convention passes the first 6 parameters in registers (rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9) and if need be others on the stack. You only have to adjust the stack after a call if you pushed data before the call.

Comment: The parameters to an actual BSD system call are done via registers rdi,
rsi, rdx, r10, r8 and r9, The System call number is in _RAX_.

Comment: I just assumed the system call would pop the values from the stack so that it wouldn't be necessary to manually clean up the stack. Just trying to understand why one must do that. Obviously my understanding of the mechanism is incomplete, which is why I ask. The code examples in the handbook don't explain why this is necessary, and I don't recall ever doing this in my DOS programming days.

Comment: In 32-bit code `int 0x80` is used for system calls. the calling convention for `int 0x80` requires pushing parameters on the stack, and `int 0x80` requires the caller to restore the stack itself. If you push parameters on the stack for `int 0x80` the space must be reclaimed afterwards. In 64-bit code the system calls are done through the `syscall` instruction. In that case system call parameters are all passed in registers. In that case there is no need to adjust _RSP_ after a `syscall` instruction.

Comment: I was referring to the FreeBSD developer's handbook, chapter 11. The examples are 32-bit (which is why I asked if this was also required in 64-bit code.) The UNIX filter example (which I specifically noted) inludes `add esp byte 12`, essentially rolling back the stack by the three double words that you just pushed there. I'm asking if this is really necessary, why, and whether it is still needed in 64-bit asm.

Comment: If you read my first comment I put a link to the documentation I thought you were referencing (and I was correct). Your question never actually gave a link. I took a guess. That's why people like zwol asked for a link.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary in 32-bit code because `int 0x80` doesn't remove parameters from the stack. That is required of the `int 0x80` calling convention. In _DOS_ and _BIOS_ interrupt calls usually passed parameters in registers so there was no need to adjust the stack pointer after.

Comment: I appreciate the response, Michael Petch; you've answered my question beautifully.

Comment: For more information on the `int 0x80` system call interface in 32-bit code, the FreeBSD documentation has a section on that: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html

Comment: I looked at the previous page in the FreeBSD docs. I see where your confusion lies about the code they showed. The reality is that the code where _ESP_ is not adjusted afterwards could be considered correct, but promoting a bad habit in general. It also keeps their documentation inconsistent. `add esp, byte xxx` isn't necessary in these simple cases because they aren't returning back to a calling function when complete. They are doing a sys.exit system call which will tear down the process. Code after the system exit call will never return so the state of the stack doesn't matter.

Comment: If you created a function in assembly that ended with `ret` that made a system call then making sure the stack is properly adjusted would be required. failure to cleanup the stack before a `ret` will cause your program to return to the wrong place in memory and more than likely crash the application.

Comment: As for the 64-bit question, since system calls (via `syscall` instruction) don't use the stack and all parameters for a system call are in registers there is nothing to be pushed on the stack, and thus nothing to clean up after.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: am I right in assuming that in the first, simple example, the code *should have* actually adjusted ESP too, but it wasn't done because the program is exiting anyway, so the state of the stack is unimportant at that stage?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis : The first example should have had the `add esp, 12` in my opinion to keep their examples consistent, but correct they aren't required in either of the examples because the system exit (via `int 0x80`) will close the process and won't care that the state of the stack at program entry was not the same at the time of the exit. I think the documentation should be amended to keep the examples consistent and that as good form should probably have adjusted ESP after so that questions like this don't get raised ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks for confirming that. I also think they should have added it to the first example too, for reasons of consistency.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Agreed, they should have made it consistent and had the stack adjustment in each. Most especially if people copy and paste the code (without the stack cleanup) into a function and then wonder why their function never returns properly(and likely seg faults). The only thing I can think of is that they did it in the first example was because there was a loop that would eat up more stack space on each iteration otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

FreeBSD uses the calling convention that caller clears stack after another function call. Just after call, the stack contains all function arguments. The request to clear stack from function arguments by adjusting its position immediatelt after the function call is the simplest way to implement proper stack maintaining. But this is not the only way. For example, you can write:

```
; print a first thing
push    dword len1
push    dword buffer1
push    dword stdout
sys.write
; here, 12 bytes in stack aren't retired yet
; print a second thing
push    dword len2
push    dword buffer2
push    dword stdout
sys.write
add esp, byte 24 ; clean stack after _both_ write() calls
```

This optimization is really used, for example, in GCC.

If you *return* from the function, you shall restore stack position after all function calls. But how exactly it is done, it's fully up to you, provided all stack manipulations are correct.

So, what is special in the last example (with sys.exit)? The particularity is that you do *not* return from it. Sys.exit doesn't return, it simply stops the whole process. So, restoring stack position is unimportant here.

Comment: Or instead of piling up more args with `push`, you (or gcc) can just use `mov` stores into the already-reserved space.